# Display content next to the thumbnails

Tags: html, css

I hope you are all doing well.

I am creating a Wordpress website and I am using the "Display Eventbrite Events" Plugin to showcase a List of my events.
Everything works just fine, but I would love to know if there's a way to display all the content of each event on the right hand side of its thumbnail instead of below it, since the Plugin doesn't offer that option.

It would only be for the desktop version.

[The page I need help with](https://abbeyelizabethsykes.com/cacao-ceremonies/)

[A screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYwkI.jpg)

I appreciate any help or advice in advance.

Thank you and have a good night.

Juan Manuel

Comment: you can use `display:flex;`

Comment: If you're actually doing web-dev, display: flex or grid are the answer, but since you're hacking a wordpress plugin and likely don't have full control over the dom structure, neither of those is going to work for you. Honestly I'd just throw a `float: left; margin-right: 10px` on the image and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're actually doing web-dev, display: flex or grid are the answer, but since you're hacking a wordpress plugin and likely don't have full control over the dom structure, neither of those is going to work for you. Honestly I'd just throw a `float: left;` on the image and you're good to go.

```css
.eaw-li.eaw-clearfix {
    overflow: auto;
}

.eaw-li > span {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hey xdumaine! This made the trick! Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1: Flex

Like groot said in his comment, you can use a `display` of `flex` to achieve this. This is because `flex` by default displays items side by side.

```css
element: {
   display: flex;
}
```

Read more about [display:flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

## Method 2: Grid & Columns

Another option, if you want more control, would be to use a `display: grid`. This involves a bit more tweaking but could also achieve the result you want like so:

```css
element: {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   element: {
      grid-template-columns: auto;
   }
}
```

Again, both would work and grid takes a little more work (but also offer's more options). You can read more about [display:grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid).

Comment: Hey Calvin! Thank you so much for your answer, this snippet did turned all into columns but, for some reason, some of it remained below the thumbnail. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .container{
            display:flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        img{
            margin-bottom: 2rem;
        }

        p {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 316px;
        }

        .text{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-left:2rem;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <img
        src="https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F141461433%2F558965351551%2F1%2Foriginal.20210713-072330?h=200&w=450&auto=format%2Ccompress&q=75&sharp=10&rect=0%2C116%2C1400%2C700&s=450793955342a56181aa93f964ab91b2"
        alt=""
      />
      <div class="text">
      <h1>Cacao Ceremony</h1>
       <p>July 22, 2021, 7:00 pm - 9:00 pm
        A SACRED SPACE FOR WOMEN TO COME TOGETHER AND SHARE FROM THEIR HEARTS</p> 
        <a href="#">Book Now »</a>
      
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <img
          src="https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F141346119%2F558965351551%2F1%2Foriginal.20210712-095719?h=200&w=450&auto=format%2Ccompress&q=75&sharp=10&rect=0%2C116%2C1400%2C700&s=97d8ebff4243187d0fe715857473e1a5"
          alt=""
        />
        <div class="text">
            <h1>Cacao Ceremony</h1>
            <p>July 29, 2021, 7:00 pm - 9:00 pm
                A SACRED SPACE FOR WOMEN TO COME TOGETHER AND SHARE FROM THEIR HEARTS</p>
                <a href="#">Book Now »</a>        
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Groot! Thank you so much! I didn't get to try this snippet since I tried @xdumaine's one and it worked perfectly but, again, Thank you so much for your answer!